# I am Unable to get output in this JS before loop termination

Tags: javascript, html, web, calculator

i want to get my output after every iteration of loop but it gives me output when loop is  terminated.i am unable to get why  am facing this issue as am newbie to JS. after i press N to terminate loop n prompt get closed i get output on webscreen.maybe  i look stupid but i am not able to solve it own my own n PS vote Postive for my question as i am geting question ban.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    do{
    var value1=prompt("enter 1st number::"," ");
    var value2=prompt("enter 2nd number::"," ");
    var op=prompt("Enter operator from(+,-,*,/,%age,average):");
    if (op=="+")
    {
        var result=parseInt(value1)+parseInt(value2);
        document.write("addition result is ="+result );
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else if(op=="-")
        
    {
        var result=parseInt(value1)-parseInt(value2);
        document.write("substraction result is ="+result );
    document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else if (op=="*")
    
        
    {
        var result=parseInt(value1)*parseInt(value2);
        document.write("multiplication  result is ="+result);
    document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else if (op=="/")
    
       
    {
        var result=parseInt(value1)/parseInt(value2);
        document.write("division  result is ="+result );
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else if (op=="%age")
    
       
    {
        var result=(parseInt(value1)/parseInt(value2))*100;
        document.write("percentage of value1 with value 2  is ="+result );
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else if (op=="average")
    
       
    {
        var result=(parseInt(value1)+parseInt(value2))/2;
        document.write("average   is ="+result );
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
    else
    {
       displa("Invalid input :" );
        document.write("<br/>"); 
    }
    var choice=prompt("Do you want to continue (Y/N)::"," ");
    }
    while(choice=="Y"||choice=="y");
    </script>
```

Comment: `parseInt` starts with a lowercase and JavaScript is case sensitive. You should have errors in your console for that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code `ParseInt` should be `parseInt`, additionnaly, it is recommended to use the static method of the `Number` object: `Number.parseInt` as it is generally safer.

Comment: "a*dditionnaly, it is recommended to use the static method of the `Number` object: `Number.parseInt` as it is generally safer.*" wait, who recommends that? Because that's wrong and by extension, you should be wary of any other advice you've heard from the same source. [`Number.parseInt` is *literally* the same as the global `parseInt`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.parseint).

Comment: One of my teacher used to say that. He said that it was generally safer because the `parseInt` can easily be overwritten by a function of the same name (I know `Number.parseInt` can also be overwritten, but the chances it does are lower since it requires to overwrite `Number.prototype.parseInt` which is less prone to happen). And yes I know they both do the same things, `parseInt` is just "shorter" to write.